# pyuic5 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PyQt5.sip

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5

I have just installed Anaconda 5.2 with Python 3.6 on my windows system. Also installed pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools via pip with administrator privilege. Now when I run pyuic5.exe for converting ui files it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AshfaqurRahman\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\AshfaqurRahman\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\AshfaqurRahman\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

I have tried installing PyQt5-sip package using pip. Buts its already installed in my system.

Why this problem is occurring? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you try `pip install --upgrade sip` and then `pip install --upgrade pip install PyQt5-sip`

Comment: did you mean `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install PyQt5-sip` ?

Comment: Never mind worth a try :)

Comment: In that case:

`pip install --upgrade sip` returns Already the latest version.

`pip install --upgrade pip install PyQt5-sip` returns "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install"

Comment: Try uninstalling and then again installing pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools

Comment: You can also try uninstalling pyqt and then installing `conda install -c anaconda pyqt`

Comment: It worked after after uninstalling pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools and then reinstalling!

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem. The problem went away after installing pyqt5-tools. I went through the steps of uninstalling and re-installing pyqt5 packages: 'pip uninstall pyqt5', 'pip uninstall pyqt5-tools' (Skipped as it is not installed), 'pip install pyqt5', 'pip install pyqt5-tools'. I assume that the pyqt5-tools were missing.

Comment: As of June 2019, this no longer works as trying to install pyqt5-tool gives the following error:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools`
Uninstalling and installing pyqt5 does not work either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Agile_Eagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9871094/agile-eagle)'s suggestion from the comments I just uninstalled `pyqt5` and `pyqt5-tools` packages and the reinstalled them. Problem solved!

PS.: If you still got problems with PyQt, try uninstalling all of the PyQt related libraries:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
```

Then install them again, this will fix:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

PPS.:If you got problems uninstalling the libraries, go to your Python folder, like `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<PYTHON-VERSION>\Lib\site-packages` and manually delete the PyQt folders, then uninstall everything and install again (Make sure you have the latest Python version and upgraded your pip too)

Comment: This works, though I want to mention that when you use a Linux distro's PyQt5, you have to uninstall it from the system's manager (and either temporarily breaking dependencies, or uninstalling packages that depend on PyQt).

Comment: Have no idea how uninstalling and installing worked, but it worked for me :P

Answer (score 8):

As of June 2019, pyqt5-tools no longer exists.
The solution I found was first installing `pyqt5-sip` and then install `pyqt5`

```
$ pip install pyqt5-sip

$ pip install pyqt5
```

This seems to get rid of the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'`

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers above worked for PyQt5 5.13.0 on conda's python 3.6.

With `pyqt5` and `pyqt5-sip` installed just go into python's site-packages and copy `sip.so` from the `PyQt5_sip` package to `PyQt5` folder (or make a symlink) where the rest of Qt's so modules are.

Seems like a poor decision to pull sip out into a separate package.

Comment: Thank you! this made it for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am a Mac user and I had faced a similar issue.
However, I understand for window users, what you are looking for is `pyuic5.bat` and not `pyuic5.sip`
It seems you'll simply have to provide the full path of the pyuic file(for me, it was under a hidden folder usr in the home directory: `/usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/5.10.1_1/bin/pyuic5`) and do make sure on your terminal(for you, cmd) you have the directory changed to where the *.ui file lies which you wish to convert to a *.py file.

So for instance, if you have a `Qt` designer file saved by the name untitled.ui on your desktop, put in the following command in your terminal:

```
Amars-MacBook-Pro:Desktop amaradak$ /usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/5.10.1_1/bin/pyuic5 -x untitled.ui -o untitled.py
```

Hope this helps...
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am also a MAC user, but found adding the code below fixed my problem with "no module named sip":

`from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication`

Answer (score 0):

On windows py3.10 with fresh venv it's throwing `No module named 'PyQt5.sip'.

`pyqt5-sip` is at version 12.9.1. After updating it (`pip install pyqt5-sip -U`) to version 12.11.0 it isn't throwing anymore.