# No module named PyQt5.sip

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

After upgrading to python-pyqt5 5.12-2 I get this error when I try to import from QtWidgets

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

Any idea on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: [python - pyuic5 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PyQt5.sip - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808229/pyuic5-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyqt5-sip)?

Comment: The current version of pyqt5 is 5.12, not 5.12.2. What platform are you on, and how *exactly* did you "upgrade"?

Comment: Sorry I meant 5.12-2 (I just edited the question) I'm on Manjaro Linux (KDE). I just installed the system and executed a total upgrade from pacman. I already tried deleting and reinstalling python-pyqt5 but that did not solve the problem.

(edit) Also since the update applications like Spyder3 do not work anymore (for the same error)

Comment: @Holderekt install with: `sudo pacman -S python-sip python-pyqt5 python-sip-pyqt5`

Comment: Already tried that and it still gives that error

Comment: @Holderekt This seems to be a manjaro packaging bug, so there is no point in reporting it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyuic5 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PyQt5.sip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808229/pyuic5-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyqt5-sip)

Comment: @ederag The solution given no longer works as there are no distributions of pyqt5-tools available

Comment: @HeladioAmaya Thanks for pointing that out. Then the question should mention the previous one, and state that the previous answers were tried, and do not work on this system.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is a [backward incompatible change in PyQt-5.11](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-11)

In `geoptics` this [fix](https://github.com/ederag/geoptics/pull/4/commits/b7c46211ca916fce360e2d1c40ef351e04caf21e) works on old and new versions:

```
try:
    # new location for sip
    # https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#pyqt-v5-11
    from PyQt5 import sip
except ImportError:
    import sip
```

Answer (score 10):

As suggested here [pyuic5 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named PyQt5.sip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51808229/8806187)

Try uninstalling and re-installing all PyQt related libraries:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
```

Then install them again, this will fix:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

PPS.:If you got problems uninstalling the libraries, go to your Python folder, like `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<PYTHON-VERSION>\Lib\site-packages` and manually delete the PyQt folders, them uninstall everything and install again (Make sure you have the latest Python version and upgraded your pip too)

Answer (score 3):

If you're building sip and PyQt5 from source using make files, make sure to check PyQt5 install [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html). In particular,

> Note
>
> When building PyQt5 v5.11 or later you must configure SIP to create a
>   private copy of the sip module using a command line similar to the
>   following:
>
> python configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip
>
> If you already have SIP installed and you just want to build and
>   install the private copy of the module then add the --no-tools option.

Answer (score 2):

I repaired this problem

**This problem occurred when upgrading pyqt5 version 5.15.0**

There was no problem when I reverted to the previous version.

I have
python -V: 3.7.4

PYQT5 5.14.1 and PYSIDE 5.14.1 works fine

Answer (score 1):

You should add PyQt5.sip to hidden imports; that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by Tadeu (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880976/12455023) I would also suggest checking version of your libraries to make sure that they match.

Use `pip show <library_name>`

This will help you to make sure that no earlier installation is conflicting with your current installation.

In place of library_name use `PyQt5`, `PyQt5-sip`, `PyQtWebEngine`. If any of them is present in the system, then use `pip uninstall <library_name>==<version_number>` to remove that library.

Once you made sure that no other versions of these libraries are there, then you can reinstall the preferred version of that library.