# No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I have instlled PyQtWebEngine module with pip but I get this python error:

> No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

my code is :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(r'C:\Users\Hss\Desktop\hi.html'))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how i solve this problem?(All library is updated)

Comment: install with: `python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine`

Comment: it was not work.

Comment: How are you running your .py? Do you do it in the cmd or do you use any IDE?

Comment: i try this code in both ide and cmd

Comment: eyllanesc's comment solved the same issue I had. Please provide it as an answer.

Comment: You can refer the answer given below, which was given for pyqt5-sip, which is also applicable for your issue. 

Ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087069/no-module-named-pyqt5-sip

Answer (score 0):

try the repair option on your python installer or try reinstalling python or the IDE