# PyInstaller weird PyQt5.sip import causes a failed EXE

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

PyInstaller builds EXE package and when I try to launch it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aplikacja.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
[75157] Failed to execute script 'aplikacja' due to unhandled exception!
```

Here's my imports from source file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import numpy as np

import PyQt5.uic as uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from Video import VideoThread
import Language as Lang
```

So it points on

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
```

I cannot understand where there is `PyQt5.sip` import?

##### Note

I tested if error would still point on the same line while moving it around

So far I tried:

```
python3 -m PyInstaller --windowed --hidden-import=PyQt5.sip --noconsole aplikacja.py
```

Aswell as with params:

- `--onefile`,
- without `--nonsole`,
- without `--hidden-import=PyQt5.sip`;

and every time same error appears.

##### I was thinking it has something to do with:

```
import PyQt5.uic as uic
```

or

```
from PyQt5 import uic
```

because PyCharm pointed and unresolved import, when I ignored it, application was running without any errors.

##### Note

I tried both lines, still resulted with same error.

##### Ps.

It built and ran without any problems when I did not use `uic` but app got to big to maintain so I switched to .ui files

Comment: From your question it is not clear if `from PyQt5 import uic` *does* cause the error.

Comment: @musicamante I can only tell you that when I was moving around line ```from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets```, error followed up and still pointed at that line.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear: does the error still happen if you do `from PyQt5 import uic` instead of `import PyQt5.uic as uic`? Those two lines, although similar in effect, are not always the same thing.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, they cause same error, originally I had ```from PyQt5 import uic```

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55087069

Comment: @musicamante Thanks! Apparently if you install debian pyqt5 packages and pip PyQt5 packages they do weird staff like this...

Comment: Well, you should *not* install related packages using different installation methods. So, does that post solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it solved my issue. Now I'm aware of duplicaiting packages...